# Stripping non printable characters from a string in python

Tags: python, string, non-printable

I use to run

```
$s =~ s/[^[:print:]]//g;
```

on Perl to get rid of non printable characters.

In Python there's no POSIX regex classes, and I can't write [:print:] having it mean what I want. I know of no way in Python to detect if a character is printable or not.

What would you do?

EDIT: It has to support Unicode characters as well. The string.printable way will happily strip them out of the output. 
curses.ascii.isprint will return false for any unicode character.

Comment: With the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, it is as easy as `regex.sub(r'[^[:print:]]+', '', text)`. But of course, there are a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Iterating over strings is unfortunately rather slow in Python. Regular expressions are over an order of magnitude faster for this kind of thing. You just have to build the character class yourself. The *unicodedata* module is quite helpful for this, especially the *unicodedata.category()* function. See [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) for descriptions of the categories.

```
import unicodedata, re, itertools, sys

all_chars = (chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode))
categories = {'Cc'}
control_chars = ''.join(c for c in all_chars if unicodedata.category(c) in categories)
# or equivalently and much more efficiently
control_chars = ''.join(map(chr, itertools.chain(range(0x00,0x20), range(0x7f,0xa0))))

control_char_re = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))

def remove_control_chars(s):
    return control_char_re.sub('', s)
```

For Python2

```
import unicodedata, re, sys

all_chars = (unichr(i) for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode))
categories = {'Cc'}
control_chars = ''.join(c for c in all_chars if unicodedata.category(c) in categories)
# or equivalently and much more efficiently
control_chars = ''.join(map(unichr, range(0x00,0x20) + range(0x7f,0xa0)))

control_char_re = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))

def remove_control_chars(s):
    return control_char_re.sub('', s)
```

For some use-cases, additional categories (e.g. all from the *control* group might be preferable, although this might slow down the processing time and increase memory usage significantly. Number of characters per category:

- `Cc` (control):         65
- `Cf` (format):         161
- `Cs` (surrogate):     2048
- `Co` (private-use): 137468
- `Cn` (unassigned):  836601

***Edit** Adding suggestions from the comments.*

Comment: Is 'Cc' enough here?  I don't know, I'm just asking -- it seems to me that some of the other 'C' categories may be candidates for this filter as well.

Comment: This code doesn't work in 2.6 or 3.2, which version does it run in?

Comment: This function, as published, removes half of the Hebrew characters. I get the same effect for both of the methods given.

Comment: From performance perspective, wouldn't string.translate() work faster in this case? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: This fails for a "narrow" build of python (16-bit unicode). That's the standard build for Mac. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105874/

Comment: @ants aasma: pls tell me, how can your approach of building a character class be used to count the control chars in the string (not strip them)?  I don't see any suitable method in re.

Comment: @Edward Falk: For the narrow build, put all_chars = (unichr(i) for i in xrange(0x110000) in a try clause, then same with xrange(0x10000) in the except clause -- allows it to work with a "Narrow" build (like OSX)

Comment: @PatrickJohnmeyer You've got a good point, and this bit me.  I fixed it by checking if the unicodedata.category(c) is in a set of any of the 'Other' unicode categories (see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm ), ie set(['Cc','Cf','Cn','Co','Cs']).  Note that I'm using English fonts, so ymmv using other fonts.

Comment: Use `all_chars = (unichr(i) for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode))` to avoid the narrow build error.

Comment: For me `control_chars == '\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f'` (tested on Python 3.5.2)

Comment: can i apply this on pandas dataframe, if yes please explain how

Comment: On Python3 use `chr()` instead of `unichr()` and `range()` instead of `xrange()`. Furthermore, for combination of the two iterators returned by `range()` one should use `itertools.chain()`: `itertools.chain(range(), range())`. For readability, I suggest to use hex numbers (thanks @AXO) in the static ranges: `range(0x00,0x20)` and `range(0x7f,0xa0)`.

Answer (score 84):

As far as I know, the most pythonic/efficient method would be:

```
import string

filtered_string = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, myStr)
```

Comment: You probably want 

    filtered_string = ''.join(filter(lambda x:x in string.printable, myStr)

so that you get back a string.

Comment: Sadly string.printable does not contain unicode characters, and thus ü or ó will not be in the output... maybe there is something else?

Comment: You should be using a list comprehension or generator expressions, not filter + lambda. One of these will 99.9% of the time be faster. ''.join(s for s in myStr if s in string.printable)

Comment: The lot of you are correct, of course.
I should stop trying to help people while sleep-deprived!

Comment: @AaronGallagher: 99.9% faster? From whence do you pluck that figure? The performance comparison is nowhere near that bad.

Comment: It's perhaps worth turning `string.printable` into a `set` before doing the filter.

Comment: Hi William. This method seems to remove all non-ASCII characters. There are many printable non-ASCII characters in Unicode!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Late response, but the claim is it will almost always be faster, not that it will be much, much faster.

Comment: Be aware: In Python3, filter returns a generator. So either use Nathans `''.join(...)` or `str(filter(...))`

Comment: Here's my version that gives a clue about what was eliminated:  ''.join(  (s if s in string.printable else 'X')  for s in s_string_to_print )

Comment: Not that tab, newline and a few more are part of the printable characters. So if you don't want to include those, you should use `string.printable[:-5]`

Comment: bad idea! "עברית" is printable but it gets filtered out

Answer (score 20):

You could try setting up a filter using the `unicodedata.category()` function:

```
import unicodedata
printable = {'Lu', 'Ll'}
def filter_non_printable(str):
  return ''.join(c for c in str if unicodedata.category(c) in printable)
```

See Table 4-9 on page 175 in the [Unicode database character properties](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch04.pdf) for the available categories

Comment: you started a list comprehension which did not end in your final line. I suggest you remove the opening bracket completely.

Comment: This seems the most direct, straightforward method. Thanks.

Comment: it should be `printable = set(['Lu', 'Ll'])` shouldn't it ?

Comment: @FabrizioMiano You are right. Or set(('Lu', 'Ll')) Thanx

Comment: @Ber You meant to say `printable = {'Lu', 'Ll'}` ?

Comment: @CsabaToth All three are valid and yield the same set. Your's is maybe the nicest way to specify a set literal.

Comment: @Ber All of them result with the same set, certain linters advise you to use the one I advised.

Comment: but this removes the space in the string. How to maintain the space in the string?

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani You can add more Unicode categories to the filter. To reserve spaces and digits in addition to letters use `printable = {'Lu', 'Ll', Zs', 'Nd'}`

Comment: I suggest removing only control characters. See my answer for an example.

Comment: I found that after adding `'Zs'` to include spaces this method did not strip the `'\xa0'` character which Python does not seem to print. It is a 'non-breaking space' apparently. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python) you need to remove this manually which is a pain.

Comment: `Lo` seems also printable, 麵 is an example

Answer (score 17):

The following will work with Unicode input and is rather fast...

```
import sys

# build a table mapping all non-printable characters to None
NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE = {
    i: None for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode + 1) if not chr(i).isprintable()
}

def make_printable(s):
    """Replace non-printable characters in a string."""

    # the translate method on str removes characters
    # that map to None from the string
    return s.translate(NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE)


assert make_printable('Café') == 'Café'
assert make_printable('\x00\x11Hello') == 'Hello'
assert make_printable('') == ''
```

My own testing suggests this approach is faster than functions that iterate over the string and return a result using `str.join`.

Comment: This is the only answer that works for me with unicode characters. Awesome that you provided test cases!

Comment: If you want to allow for line breaks, add `LINE_BREAK_CHARACTERS = set(["\n", "\r"])` and `and not chr(i) in LINE_BREAK_CHARACTERS` when building the table.

Answer (score 13):

In Python 3,

```
def filter_nonprintable(text):
    import itertools
    # Use characters of control category
    nonprintable = itertools.chain(range(0x00,0x20),range(0x7f,0xa0))
    # Use translate to remove all non-printable characters
    return text.translate({character:None for character in nonprintable})
```

See [this StackOverflow post on removing punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) for how .translate() compares to regex & .replace()

The ranges can be generated via `nonprintable = (ord(c) for c in (chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode)) if unicodedata.category(c)=='Cc')` using the [Unicode character database categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) as shown by @Ants Aasma.

Comment: It would be better to use Unicode ranges (see @Ants Aasma's answer). The result would be `text.translate({c:None for c in itertools.chain(range(0x00,0x20),range(0x7f,0xa0))})`.

Answer (score 8):

This function uses list comprehensions and str.join, so it runs in linear time instead of O(n^2):

```
from curses.ascii import isprint

def printable(input):
    return ''.join(char for char in input if isprint(char))
```

Answer (score 7):

Yet another option in python 3:

```
re.sub(f'[^{re.escape(string.printable)}]', '', my_string)
```

Comment: for some reason this works great on windows but cant use it on linux, i had to change the f for an r but i am not sure that is the solution.

Comment: Sounds like your Linux Python was too old to support f-strings then. r-strings are quite different, though you could say `r'[^' + re.escape(string.printable) + r']'`. (I don't think `re.escape()` is entirely correct here, but if it works...)

Comment: Sadly string.printable does not contain unicode characters, and thus ü or ó will not be in the output...

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Ber's answer, I suggest removing only control characters as defined in the [Unicode character database categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values):

```py
import unicodedata
def filter_non_printable(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if not unicodedata.category(c).startswith('C'))
```

Comment: You may be on to something with `startswith('C')` but this was far less performant in my testing than any other solution.

Comment: big-mclargehuge: The goal of my solution was the combination of completeness and simplicity/readability. You could try to use `if unicodedata.category(c)[0] != 'C'` instead. Does it perform better? If you prefer execution speed over memory requirements, one can pre-compute the table as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/93029/3779655

Answer (score 5):

An elegant pythonic solution to stripping 'non printable' characters from a string in python is to use the isprintable() string method together with a generator expression or list comprehension depending on the use case ie. size of the string:

```
    ''.join(c for c in my_string if c.isprintable())
```

str.isprintable()
Return True if all characters in the string are printable or the string is empty, False otherwise. Nonprintable characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Other” or “Separator”, excepting the ASCII space (0x20) which is considered printable. (Note that printable characters in this context are those which should not be escaped when repr() is invoked on a string. It has no bearing on the handling of strings written to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.)

Answer (score 4):

The best I've come up with now is (thanks to the python-izers above)

```
def filter_non_printable(str):
  return ''.join([c for c in str if ord(c) > 31 or ord(c) == 9])
```

This is the only way I've found out that works with Unicode characters/strings

Any better options?

Comment: Unless you're on python 2.3, the inner []s are redundant. "return ''.join(c for c ...)"

Comment: Not quite redundant—they have different meanings (and performance characteristics), though the end result is the same.

Comment: Should the other end of the range not be protected too?: "ord(c) <= 126"

Comment: But there are Unicode characters which are not printable, too.

Answer (score 3):

> In Python there's no POSIX regex classes

There are when using the `regex` library: https://pypi.org/project/regex/

It is well maintained and supports Unicode regex, Posix regex and many more. The usage (method signatures) is **very** similar to Python's `re`.

From the documentation:

> `[[:alpha:]]; [[:^alpha:]]`
>
> POSIX character classes are supported. These
>   are normally treated as an alternative form of `\p{...}`.

(I'm not affiliated, just a user.)

Answer (score 2):

The one below performs faster than the others above. Take a look

```
''.join([x if x in string.printable else '' for x in Str])
```

Comment: `"".join([c if 0x21<=ord(c) and ord(c)<=0x7e else "" for c in ss])`

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from answers by [Ants Aasma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93029/5306011) and [shawnrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25829509/5306011):

```
nonprintable = set(map(chr, list(range(0,32)) + list(range(127,160))))
ord_dict = {ord(character):None for character in nonprintable}
def filter_nonprintable(text):
    return text.translate(ord_dict)

#use
str = "this is my string"
str = filter_nonprintable(str)
print(str)
```

tested on Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 1):

To remove 'whitespace',

```
import re
t = """
\n\t<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\t<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\t<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\t<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\t<p>
"""
pat = re.compile(r'[\t\n]')
print(pat.sub("", t))
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the square brackets either then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Error description
   Run the copied and pasted python code report:

Python invalid non-printable character U+00A0

2. The cause of the error
   The space in the copied code is not the same as the format in Python;
3. Solution
   Delete the space and re-enter the space. For example, the red part in the above picture is an abnormal space. Delete and re-enter the space to run;

Source : [Python invalid non-printable character U+00A0](https://blog.karatos.in/a?ID=01800-42a1f28f-71b6-497e-9a94-072b6234b28d)

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
import sys
import unicodedata

# the test string has embedded characters, \u2069 \u2068
test_string = """"ABC⁩.⁨ 6", "}"""
nonprintable = list((ord(c) for c in (chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode)) if
                        unicodedata.category(c) in ['Cc','Cf']))

translate_dict = {character: None for character in nonprintable}
print("Before translate, using repr()", repr(test_string))
print("After translate, using repr()", repr(test_string.translate(translate_dict)))
```