# Match unicode in ply's regexes

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ply, character-properties

I'm matching identifiers, but now I have a problem: my identifiers are allowed to contain unicode characters. Therefore the old way to do things is not enough:

```
t_IDENTIFIER = r"[A-Za-z](\\.|[A-Za-z_0-9])*"
```

In [my markup language](http://freehg.org/u/cheery/aml/) parser I match unicode characters by allowing all the characters except those I explicitly use, because my markup language only has two or three of characters I need to escape that way.

How do I match all unicode characters with python regexs and ply? Also is this a good idea at all?

I'd want to let people use identifiers like Ω » « ° foo² väli π as an identifiers (variable names and such) in their programs. Heck! I want that people could write programs in their own language if it's practical! Anyway unicode is supported nowadays in wide variety of places, and it should spread.

Edit: POSIX character classes doesnt seem to be recognised by python regexes.

```
>>> import re
>>> item = re.compile(r'[[:word:]]')
>>> print item.match('e')
None
```

Edit: To explain better what I need. I'd need a regex -thing that matches all the unicode printable characters but not ASCII characters at all.

Edit: r"\w" does a bit stuff what I want, but it does not match « », and I also need a regex that does not match numbers.

Comment: It also does not appear that Python PCRE understands predicate classes either: \p{IsAlpha}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re#regular-expression-syntax) module supports the \w syntax which:

> If UNICODE is set, this will match the
>   characters [0-9_] plus whatever is
>   classified as alphanumeric in the
>   Unicode character properties database.

therefore the following examples shows how to match unicode identifiers:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.compile('(?u)[^\W0-9]\w*')
>>> m.match('a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7d75410>
>>> m.match('9')
>>> m.match('ab')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7c258e0>
>>> m.match('a9')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7d75410>
>>> m.match('unicöde')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7c258e0>
>>> m.match('ödipus')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7d75410>
```

So the expression you look for is: (?u)[^\W0-9]\w*

Comment: Now. This is a satisfying solution!

Comment: The quote from the Python documentation is correct, but the examples are misleading. You can simple use the UNICODE flag with \w in stead of the unnecessarily long expression given: `re.match(r'\w+', "ünıcodê", re.UNICODE)`

Comment: Walter, you have not properly read the question: 1) the goal is an identifier in a programming language, which does not start with 0-9 usually. 2) the parser (ply) takes care of parsing, and it can't be controlled how it will invoke match, therefore (?u) is required.

Comment: Re: controlling how ply invokes match, see Stanislav's answer below

Answer (score 4):

You need pass pass parameter reflags in lex.lex:

```
lex.lex(reflags=re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the answers to this question

[Stripping non printable characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

you'd just need to use the other unicode character categories instead

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of Vinko.

I realised that getting unicode range is plain dumb. So I'll do this:

```
symbols = re.escape(''.join([chr(i) for i in xrange(33, 127) if not chr(i).isalnum()]))
symnums = re.escape(''.join([chr(i) for i in xrange(33, 127) if not chr(i).isalnum()]))

t_IDENTIFIER = "[^%s](\\.|[^%s])*" % (symnums, symbols)
```

I don't know about unicode character classses. If this unicode stuff starts getting too complicated, I can just put the original one in place. UTF-8 support still ensures the support is on at the STRING tokens, which is more important.

Edit: On other hand, I start understanding why there's not much unicode support in programming languages.. This is an ugly hack, not a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) are right for you?

Comment: They don't exist in Python's regex engine