# Python regex to match non-ascii names

Tags: python, regex, validation, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to validate name fields with the re module.

`\w` doesn't match non-ascii chars such as `à`.

It seems that in many other regex engines, the solution would have been `\p{L}`, but this isn't supported in python as it appears. What would be a suitable equivalent?

**Update:**

This is different from other questions around this topic, in that I'm looking for the unicode alternative to `\w` which isn't the one obtained using the default `re.UNICODE` flag (since this flag also makes `\w` match digits and underscores).

Comment: Are you using the [LOCALE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.LOCALE) and/or [UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flags?

Comment: yeah, each `re.<function>` has a `flags` argument.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238223/match-unicode-in-plys-regexes for a similar (duplicate?) question.

Comment: @BrenBarn I've tried re.UNICODE but it's not suitable since it also matches digits and underscores

Comment: @GJ.: to your update: the indicated duplicate states "and I also need a regex that does **not match numbers**." Is the underscore-handling the only difference then?

Comment: \w matches digits and underscores regardless of the UNICODE flag being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\W0-9_]` works for me, when used together with `re.UNICODE`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thanks for the reference, this was hiding in a partial form inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to enable unicode support for character classes, with the UNICODE modifier.

```
regexRef = re.compile("\w", re.UNICODE)
```

See if that helps to match those non-ASCII characters.

Comment: re.UNICODE doesn't solve this problem since it also matches digits and underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Does `[^\d\s_]` match what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Pass Unicode strings to `re` module and enable `re.UNICODE` flag, example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

print(re.findall(ur"\w+", ur"\w does match à.", flags=re.UNICODE))
```