# Add special key as a delimeter for CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

In my csv file the data is separated by a special character. When I view in Notepad++ it shows 'SOH'.

```
ATT_AI16601A.PV01-Apr-2014 05:02:192.94752310FalseFalseFalse

ATT_AI16601A.PV[]01-Apr-2014 05:02:19[]2.947523[]1[]0[]False[]False[]False[]
```

It is present in the data but not visible. I have put markers in the second string where those characters are.
My point is that I need to read that data in Python delimited by these markers. How can I use these special characters as delimiters while reading data?

Comment: is that special character is ascii or non-ascii

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split line at non-printing ascii character in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936174/how-to-split-line-at-non-printing-ascii-character-in-python)

Comment: @Ivan i am talking about csv delimeter.
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='[]')

Comment: @nishantkumar it is an ascii control character with code 01
refrence http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: You should be able to read it with the `csv` module by specifying it as the delmiter: i.e. `reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\x01')` This is because `SOH` is an ASCII control character with a code point of `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python csv module by specifying `,` as delimiter like this.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='what ever is your delimiter')
```

In your case

```
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\x01')
```

This is because SOH is an ASCII control character with a code point of 1