# ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)

Tags: python, html

I am trying to convert the html entity to unichar, the html entity is `&#976918;`
when i try to do the following:

```
unichr(int(976918))
```

I got error that:

```
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```

seems like it is out of range conversion for unichar.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can decode a string that has a Unicode escape (`\U` followed by 8 hex digits, zero-padded) using the `"unicode-escape"` encoding:

```
>>> s = "\\U%08x" % 976918
>>> s
'\\U000ee816'

>>> c = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> c
u'\U000ee816'
```

On a narrow build it's stored as a UTF-16 surrogate pair:

```
>>> list(c)
[u'\udb7a', u'\udc16']
```

This surrogate pair is processed correctly as a code unit during encoding:

```
>>> c.encode('utf-8')
'\xf3\xae\xa0\x96'

>>> '\xf3\xae\xa0\x96'.decode('utf-8')
u'\U000ee816'
```

Comment: To convert 976918 to 000ee816 do `hex(976918)[2:].zfill(8)`

Answer (score 13):

Here's an alternate workaround that I developed with the `struct` module.

```
def unichar(i):
    try:
        return unichr(i)
    except ValueError:
        return struct.pack('i', i).decode('utf-32')

>>> unichar(int('976918'))
u'\U000ee816'
```

Answer (score 6):

In order for this to work, you either need to build Python yourself, specifying

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

before compiling, or else you need to move to Python 3.

Even if you do this, there are apparently problems on Windows, which will be fixed in the next version of Python (3.3).