# Python - Reading Emoji Unicode Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, emoji

I have a Python 2.7 program which reads iOS text messages from a SQLite database.  The text messages are unicode strings.  In the following text message:

```
u'that\u2019s \U0001f63b'
```

The apostrophe is represented by `\u2019`, but the emoji is represented by `\U0001f63b`.  I looked up the code point for the emoji in question, and it's `\uf63b`.  I'm not sure where the `0001` is coming from.  I know comically little about character encodings.

When I print the text, character by character, using:

```
s = u'that\u2019s \U0001f63b'

for c in s:
    print c.encode('unicode_escape')
```

The program produces the following output:

```
t
h
a
t
\u2019
s

\ud83d
\ude3b
```

How can I correctly read these last characters in Python?  Am I using encode correctly here?  Should I just attempt to trash those `0001`s before reading it, or is there an easier, less silly way?

Comment: `0xf63b` is in the "Private Use" section of Unicode. Are you sure this is correct? Your codepoint is probably `0x1f63b`, as that's a "smiling cat with heart eyes" emoji.

Comment: How did you determine that `\uf63b` would be an Emoji character? According to my reference, it's undefined: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f63b/index.htm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you're using encode correctly, nor do you need to. What you have is a valid unicode string with one 4 digit and one 8 digit escape sequence. Try this in the REPL on, say, OS X

```
>>> s = u'that\u2019s \U0001f63b'
>>> print s
that’s
```

In python3, though -

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul  7 2015, 15:40:07) 
>>> s  = u'that\u2019s \U0001f63b'
>>> s[-1]
''
```

Comment: Well would ya look at that... I really know nothing about nothing.  Thanks!  I'm still not clear how to read just that last character though.  s[-1] and s[-2] still give '\ud83d' and '\ude3b'.  Is there a way to read the string character by character?

Comment: @alaprise you're seeing an artifact of the way Python stores its Unicode strings internally. If you did the same thing in Python 3 you'd see something different entirely.

Comment: @alaprise The other answer has some good info, of which the summary is 'if possible move to Python3'. Otherwise you're entering a world of pain/surrogate pairs/words you don't want to know for they are the song of Cthulhu

Comment: '\ud83d' and '\ude3b' is a surrogate pair, used by UTF-16 to represent a code point above `U+FFFF`. This is a bug in Python 2, a lot of languages have that problem with those characters.

Comment: @roeland: `s[-1] == u'\U0001f63b'` on both Python 2 and 3 on my machine (["wide Python builds" are supported since 2001](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/))

Comment: @alaprise: see [How to install python on Mac with wide-build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25111521/4279)

Comment: I cant get this working with the warning sign:  u'\U000026A0' - it comes out as a text glyph not emoji.

Answer (score 3):

Your last part of confusion is likely due to the fact that you are running what is called a "narrow Python build". Python can't hold a single character with enough information to hold a single emoji. The best solution would be to move to Python 3. Otherwise, try to process the [UTF-16 surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105874/valueerror-unichr-arg-not-in-range0x10000-narrow-python-build-please-hel).

Comment: `regex.findall(r'\X', unicode_text)` could be used to get "user-perceived characters" that may span more than one Unicode codepoint (it is unrelated to surrogate pairs but it should fix the issue as a side effect).