# how to convert unicode character (\u00a3) to human readable string (£) in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a method where I receive data from 3rd party something like this

```
def func(**kwagrs):
    print kwagrs
```

**output**
{'payload': u'{"id":"50b4f4b3e319586b10230f68d21f5edb","data":{"message":"message is \\u00a3 150 \\u2192\\u00c5\\u25024\\u00e9","length":47}}'}

How to convert \\u00a3 to £ in python
also, you have notice value type for the payload is Unicode not dictionary or JSON
I tried to find the similar issue in StackOverflow but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With aid of [ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105874/valueerror-unichr-arg-not-in-range0x10000-narrow-python-build), I came to

```
import struct
def unichar(i):
    try:
        return unichr(i)
    except ValueError:
        return struct.pack('i', i).decode('utf-32')

def func(arg):
    msg = args['payload']['data']['message']
    # msg = 'message is \\u00a3 150 \\u2192\\u00c5\\u25024\\u00e9'
    print ' '.join(''.join([unichar(int(ch, 16)) for ch in chunk.split('\\u')[1:]]) if chunk.startswith('\\u') else
    chunk for chunk in msg.split(' '))

func({'payload':{'data':{'message':"message is \\u00a3 150 \\u2192\\u00c5\\u25024\\u00e9"}}})
```

If we run the code above, we get **message is £ 150 →Åé**.
Note: We may have better parsing code...