# How to convert large codepoint to unicode character in python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I got the following error. Does anybody know how to get the Unicode character corresponding to a large code point? Thanks.

```
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 29 2018, 20:59:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> unichr(119964)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105874/valueerror-unichr-arg-not-in-range0x10000-narrow-python-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your python is configured as UCS2. From the documentation

> Return the Unicode string of one character whose Unicode code is the
>   integer i. For example, unichr(97) returns the string u'a'. This is
>   the inverse of ord() for Unicode strings. The valid range for the
>   argument depends how Python was configured – it may be either UCS2
>   [0..0xFFFF] or UCS4 [0..0x10FFFF]. ValueError is raised otherwise. For
>   ASCII and 8-bit strings see chr().

As has been posted above in a comment [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105874/valueerror-unichr-arg-not-in-range0x10000-narrow-python-build) question has various answers that my provide you with a workaround.

Comment: I use the python 2 installation package from python website for Mac. How to get the USC4 installation package?