# Linux more: remove nonprintable characters

Tags: python, linux

I am using Python to capture the output of Linux more. However, the file contains the characters:

> <--- More --->^M              ^M

How do I use Python to clean the lines? Or use more once more time to cleanit up?

Comment: If you are capturing the output in a program why do you need to use `more`?  Just capture the output without piping it through `more`.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: The program that I am exec'ing is using 'more'.. I cann't do anything

Answer (score 2):

This isn't guaranteed to work, but you should try setting `PAGER` to `cat` in the environment of the child process.  You can't do that with `subprocess.call` but you can do it with `subprocess.Popen`:

```
childenv = os.environ.copy()
childenv['PAGER'] = 'cat'

proc = subprocess.Popen(executable="yourprogram",
                        args=["yourprogram", ...],
                        env=childenv,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        ...)

# proc.stdout *may* now be free of `more` detritus
```