# Encoding in Coldfusion - Observing a weird value from query result

Tags: json, coldfusion, removing-whitespace

I'm just running a query and forming a JSON string in `cfloop`.

For some values that are formed within JSON, I see some bogus extra characters at the end. At first, I suspected them to be white spaces or tabs but adding a `Trim(name)` did not work.

```
"first_name":"Jon   "
```

When I copied the string over to Notepad++ and converted it to utf-8, Here is what I am seeing:

```
"first_name":"Jon  **xA0**"
```

I am not sure what that xA0 means here. Is there any way to supress this?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a non breaking space. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing with this

```
<cfset lastname = replacelist(lastname, chr(160), '')>
```

Comment: This is probably treating a symptom rather than the underlying problem. Where's the hard-space *coming from*?