# PHP IF OR AND not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have problems to make IF OR statement properly, in this case it does not matter if I use || or "OR".

I have now:
`if($email == '' || (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))`

I get error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function \xa0() in`

if I change to `if($email == '' || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))`

I get error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '!' in`

Comment: tried your code here http://phpfiddle.org/ .. no errors were found .. code run succesfuly

Comment: So its something to apache/php configs related then ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: This function is available from 5.2.0, what version of php you are using?

Comment: This feature is only available for PHP Versions (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0) according to documentation. So make sure your version is correct.  http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: PHP 5.5.16 (cli), filter validate function it self works perfectly but the IF OR statement, it doesn't matter if I have other like $sth == '' OR/|| !functionX(...)) I still get the error(s)

Comment: filter_var() Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails. There is your problem

Comment: Show an example of a `$email` that causes the fail

Comment: Please show more code around the if statement.

Comment: Using PHP Version 5.5.38. Not sure what filter_var() got to do with it, I don't use it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message `Call to undefined function \xa0() in` looks a lot like encoding types are the source of your problem. The `\xA0` character is a bugger:

```
\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also
chr(160). You should replace it with a space. When .encode('utf-8'), it
will encode the unicode to utf-8, that means every unicode could be
represented by 1 to 4 bytes.Jun 12, 2012
```

from [Python: Removing \xa0 from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string)

The problem is you can't see it either because it's a special "whitespace" that was most probably inserted during a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> from some strange IDE or website.

This should remove them all from your file and replace them with `good whitespaces`:

```
file_put_contents('your-script-cleaned.php', 
                  str_replace('\\x0a', 
                  ' ', 
                  file_get_contents('your-script-original.php')))
```

An IDE search & replace could do the trick just as well.

Comment: Hi, this guide me to right tracks, there is something weird, file works as UTF-8 but not as ISO-8859-1, I did not however even think about this because most of if not all from this project are ISO

Comment: Encodings errors are the worse IMO (not so fond memories of single BOM character crashing a huge PHP deployment because of a silly IDE that went completely unnoticed during code reviews :S).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a non-breaking space character ([`\u00A0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) after the `||`.

Additionally PHP is stupid enough to consider that byte a viable identifier, thus it thinks

```
<nbsp>(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

is a function call, not unlike

```
myfunction(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

whereas

```
<nbsp>!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

is a syntax error (as would be `myfunction!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`), as `!` cannot be used as a binary operator).

---

**Typing such non-breaking spaces happens fairly commonly in keyboard layouts wherein you must type the pipe character `|` with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, such as the standard Finnish layout that I am using.** This occurs because you still have the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> pressed down while hitting the space bar; on many layouts <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> +                             will produce a non-breaking space. (Note that I myself used non-breaking space in my answer to make the space-bar key ;)

---

A good editor would be able to mark such an use a syntax error, or perhaps you can configure your editor to highlight such mistakes.