# Ascii encoding error during sending a mail

Tags: python, email, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am new to python and trying to receive and resend an email using poplib and smtplib:

```
    messages = [pop_conn.retr(i)[1] for i in range(1, mail_count + 1)]
    #decode messages
    messages = [[line.decode("utf-8") for line in message] for message in messages]
    # Concat messages
    messages = ["\n".join(msg) for msg in messages]
    #...        
    for message in messages:
        smtp_conn.sendmail(args.address, args.target, message)
```

In the debugger all message strings look good, but in the sendmail call following error occurs:

> ```
> msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
> ```
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 17938: ordinal not in range(128)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though whatever character `\xa0` represents does not have a representation in ASCII.  According to [this link](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a0), `\xa0` is the unicode character for a non-breaking space.

Since this is really just a space, you could try and replace all [`\xa0` characters in your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string):

```
 messages = ["\n".join(msg.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')) for msg in messages]
```

To be fair, space and non-breaking spaces function differently, so depending on where this character appears in your message, the output could look slightly different after replacing the non-breaking spaces with regular spaces.

Another option is to ignore any characters that produce any error.  This solution is not ideal because you could lose characters that end-up changing the formatting (or sometimes meaning) of your text.  Replacing the non-breaking space with a normal space is smart to do regardless, but for all other pesky characters:

```
msg.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
```

Alternatively, you can do `msg.encode("ascii", errors="replace")` but that will replace these characters with a '?' which doesn't look so nice.

Comment: It's necessary because the exception is raised in the smtplib anyways. I forgot this in my question

Comment: Well damn.  There goes that solution.  I'll remove it from my answer.  Did you try replacing the character with a space?

Comment: Yes, but than another error with unknown character '\xe4' occurs

Comment: Got it.  I've definitely gotten around this issue before but need to rediscover how.

Comment: I still don't unterstand why the libary encodes to ASCII because Utf-8 semms to be the standart email encoding. But anyways your solution works for mehr

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to encode an utf-8 character that is not in the ascii standard, as ascii. `A0` is a non-breaking space. If that's the only character that's not ascii encodable, you can just replace it with a normal space:

```
spaced_message = message.replace("\x0a", " ")
```

Otherwise, look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email#Unicode_support_in_message_bodies

Encoding strings as `utf-7` (yes, `7`) usually works, but it's officially deprecated in many systems. Utf-8 requires base64 encoding on top, which is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by editing the smtplib source code on line 859.

Replace 'ascii' on line 859

```
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
```

with 'utf-8'

```
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('utf-8')
```