# regular expressions in python need to retain special characters

Tags: python, regex

Below is my unclean text string

```
text = 'this/r/n/r/nis a non-U.S disclosures/n/n/r/r analysis agreements disclaimer./r/n/n/nPlease keep it confidential'
```

below is the regexp i'm using:

```
 ' '.join(re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', text))
```

my output is:

```
'this is a non US disclosures analysis agreements disclaimer. Please keep it confidential'
```

my expected output is:

```
 'this is a non-U.S disclosures analysis agreements disclaimer. Please keep it confidential'
```

I need to retain special characters and space between the words, there should be exactly one space.  can anyone help me to alter my regexp?

Comment: Can you provide a valid Python string literal. The one you posted will raise a SyntaxError.

Comment: changed the string literal

Comment: Are the `'/r/n/n'` in there like that or are these newlines and carriage returns like `'\r\n\n'`?

Comment: I do not believe your regex throws away punctuation (your 'output'), nor would it magically *add* some (your 'expected output').

Comment: You guys are being sticklers for detail instead of answering the question which is quite clear in my opinion

Comment: @VeltzerDoron: if the OP feels the need to lie about such trivial detail such as "this is my output", then we cannot be sure about anything else either.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you!

str = 'this/r/n/r/nis a non-U.S disclosures/n/n/r/r analysis agreements disclaimer./r/n/n/nPlease keep it confidential'

val = re.sub(r'(/.?)', " ", str); val1 = re.sub(r'\s+', " ", val)
print(val1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a more specific word barrier than \b ($ which marks the end of a string can't be placed inside square brackets so you have to make the or explicit in $|\n|\r|  and the ?= is a non consuming look ahead much like \b), also safer here is using a non greedy non empty accumulator (the + sign makes it non empty and the question mark makes it non greedy):

```
re.findall(r'[^\n\r ]+?(?=$|\n|\r| )', text)
```

> ['this',  'is',  'a',  'non-U.S',  'disclosures',  'analysis', 
>   'agreements',  'disclaimer.',  'Please',  'keep',  'it', 
>   'confidential']

Comment: what happen if my text has \t \xa0 will the above regular expression work?                                                                    
    text = 'this/r/n/r/nis a non-U.S disclosures \t \xao analysis agreements disclaimer./tPlease keep it confidential'

Comment: If your asking if there's a shortcut for every subset of the set of delimiters and special characters then the answer is no. and as for your \xa0 character, convert to utf https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566398/374437