# replacing a non ascii space character in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on with some identification numbers that are pulled from an excel spreadsheet.  They are a mixture of numbers and strings. (manually maintained excel sheet)  I loaded this into pandas and noticed some spaces in the data.  I ran a filter on my df, but only got 2 rows back.  So, I went in and ran this code:

```
for i in exceldata['CL ID #']:
    print(repr(str(i)))
```

I got some odd results back.  It seems the spaces aren't spaces at all, but some sort of weird, non ascii character.  Here are a few values and how they look printed in different ways.

```
for i in exceldata['ID']:
    print(repr(str(i)))

'502705'

'527167\xa0'

'575405\xa0'
```

...And those same values printed normally

```
exceldata['ID']

   502705
   502717 
   537545
```

I've dug around and found solutions on how to change the values.  But, here's where my request differs:  I need to clean up these odd values in a pandas dataframe.  I couldn't figure out how to do it in set logic.  It's a very easy fix, but you can't use loops on Pandas df's since you're only editing a copy, not the actual df itself.  Any help/direction is appreciated.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate.  I need to be able to iterate over a pandas dataframe, and that is the part that is tripping me up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Removing \xa0 from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the column contains a mixture of numbers and strings, you might be better off converting everything to a string and using [pandas string manipulation methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) on the column.  For instance, to replace `\xa0` with an empty string in the column:

```
exceldata['ID'] = exceldata['ID'].astype(str).str.replace(u'\xa0', '')
#                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ potentially unnecessary, depending on the format of your data
```

This will replace the `ID` column with the string representation of the values, but with the `\xa0` characters removed.

Comment: Awesome, this worked.  I really appreciate it.  I think I was missing the .astype(str)