# Pandas convert from text type to int while keeping NA or NaN

Tags: python, pandas

If I have currency column in pandas dataframe in dtype:object (text) which has values like this:

```
34500 USD
34222 USD
```

how do I convert it into integer type that allows NaN or NA to appear in column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
carDF['carPrice'] = carDF['carPrice'].astype(str).str.replace(' USD','')
carDF['carPrice'] = pd.to_numeric(carDF['carPrice'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer').astype('Int64')
```

and if you have non ASCII space in your character which you can see only if you print single row like:

```
carDF['carPrice'][0]
'34500 \xa0USD'
```

than you have to use:

```
carDF['carPrice'] = carDF['carPrice'].astype(str).str.replace(u'\xa0USD', '')
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911266/replacing-a-non-ascii-space-character-in-python-pandas)

You must run pandas version above 0.24

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

to upgrade to latest pandas if doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

We can do `str.strip`

```
carDF['carPrice'] = pd.to_numeric(carDF['carPrice'].str.strip('USD'), errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```