# TRIM in python for all whitespace characters

Tags: python

I am looking for something like `TRIM()` in python, but `.strip()` doesn't accomplish this. Here's an example:

```
>>> s.strip()
'Elvis Presley made his film debut in this tale of three brothers who, 
 while serving in the Confederate Army, steal a Union Army payroll. \xc2\xa0'

>>> s2.strip()
'Elvis Presley made his film debut in this tale of three brothers who, 
 while serving in the Confederate Army, steal a Union Army payroll.'

>>> s.strip()==s2.strip()
False
```

How would I accomplish the above -- to trim all whitespace characters at the edges of text -- where I could get `s.trim() == s2.trim()` (other than just doing a hackish `s.strip('\xc2\xa0').strip()`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string#11566398

Comment: What version of Python are you using? (2 or 3)

Comment: @payne 2.7 .is the version.

Comment: There is [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) defining what Python considers a whitespace. `\xa0` doesn't belong in that list, tho. Even `\s` in its regex engine won't recognize it as whitespace so you'll have to do your own _hackish_ approach to remove the chars you want treated as whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2.7, first convert your string to unicode and then strip:

```
s = unicode('test \xc2\xa0', "UTF-8")
s.strip()
```

yields:

```
u'test'
```

This will cause Python to recognize the `\xc2\xa0` as a Unicode non-breaking space character, and properly trim it.

Without that, Python assumes it's an ASCII string and in that character set `\xc2` and `\xa0` aren't whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the `replace` function. You can do this:

```
s1 = s1.replace('\xc2', '').replace('\xa0', '')
```

You could encapsulate this logic if you have a large number of possible characters you want to trim off:

```
def replace_many(base_string, *to_remove):
    result = base_string
    for r in to_remove:
        result = result.replace(r, '')
    return result

replace_many(s, '\xc2', '\xa0') == s2.strip()
>>> True
```

You could also implement this using `reduce`:

```
# In Python 2
result = reduce(lambda a, r: a.replace(r, ''), ['\xc2', '\xa0'], 
    initializer = base_string.strip())

# In Python 3
import functools
result = functools.reduce(lambda a, r: a.replace(r, ''), ['\xc2', 'xa0'], 
    base_string.strip())
```