# Python - Replace Special Characters from key, value in dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I have this dict:

```
dict1={'Period': '100.02\xa0minutes[2]', 'Repeat interval': '23\xa0days', 'Epoch': '25 January 2015, 00:45:13\xa0UTC[2]', 'Band': 'S Band(TT&C support)X Band(science data acquisition)', 'Bandwidth': 'up\xa0to\xa0722kbit/s\xa0download\xa0(S Band)up\xa0to\xa018.4Mbit/s\xa0download\xa0(X Band)up\xa0to\xa04kbit\xa0/s\xa0upload\xa0(S Band)'}
```

I want to replace all `\xa0 by " "`
I try this:

```
clean_dict = {key.strip(): item.strip() for key, item in dict1.items()}
```

But the output is the same.
I try this, too:

```
    new_keys = list(dict1.keys())
    new_values = list(dict1.values())
    new_keys2 = list()
    new_values2 = list()
    for element in new_keys:
        print (element)
        new_keys2.append(element.replace("\xa0", " "))
    for element in new_values:
        print(element)
        new_values2.append(element.replace("\xa0", " "))
    new_dict = dict(zip(new_keys2,new_values2))
```

But this also gives me the same output. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `replace`:

**python 3.x**

```
>>> dict2 = {k.replace(u'\xa0', ' ') : v.replace(u'\xa0', ' ') for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

or

**python 2.7**

```
>>> dict2 = {k.replace(u'\xa0', ' ') : v.replace(u'\xa0', ' ') for k, v in dict1.iteritems()}
```

The result is

```
>>> print(dict2)
{'Band': 'S Band(TT&C support)X Band(science data acquisition)',
 'Bandwidth': 'up to 722kbit/s download (S Band)up to 18.4Mbit/s download (X Band)up to 4kbit /s upload (S Band)',
 'Epoch': '25 January 2015, 00:45:13 UTC[2]',
 'Period': '100.02 minutes[2]',
 'Repeat interval': '23 days'}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
{unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", key): unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", item) for key, item in dict1.items()}
```

**Output**

```
 'Repeat interval': '23 days',
 'Epoch': '25 January 2015, 00:45:13 UTC[2]',
 'Band': 'S Band(TT&C support)X Band(science data acquisition)',
 'Bandwidth': 'up to 722kbit/s download (S Band)up to 18.4Mbit/s download (X Band)up to 4kbit /s upload (S Band)'}
```