# Win_service "Cannot start service InstallerService on computer '.'."

Tags: windows, ansible

I'm running into an issue where I'm not sure what is cause, here is the setup:
Following the [Ansible win_service doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_service_module.html#win-service-module)

`Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid`

```
ansible 2.7.5
  config file = /home/ansible/ansibleGalaxy/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 28 2018, 16:27:22) [GCC 8.2.0]
```

### Playbook:

```
- name: Update Dalet Installer service
  win_service:
    name: DaletInstallerService
    username: .\Administrator
    password: toto
    start_mode: auto
    state: started
```

Basically I want to update the credential of the service on the target machine.

And whatever setting i'm getting this error message:

```
fatal: [192.168.56.103]: FAILED! => {
    "can_pause_and_continue": false,
    "changed": false,
    "depended_by": [],
    "dependencies": [
        "Afd",
        "Tcpip"
    ],
    "description": "DaletInstallerService",
    "desktop_interact": false,
    "display_name": "DaletInstallerService",
    "exists": true,
    "msg": "Service 'DaletInstallerService (DaletInstallerService)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service DaletInstallerService on computer '.'.",
    "name": "DaletInstallerService",
    "path": "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DALET\\DaletInstaller\\DaletInstallerService.prunsrv.exe' //RS//DaletInstallerService",
    "start_mode": "auto",
    "state": "stopped",
    "username": ".\\Administrator"
}
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the full traceback was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 118, in <module>
    exit_code = cli.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 122, in run
    results = pbex.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 156, in run
    result = self._tqm.run(play=play)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 291, in run
    play_return = strategy.run(iterator, play_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py", line 325, in run
    results += self._wait_on_pending_results(iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py", line 712, in _wait_on_pending_results
    results = self._process_pending_results(iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py", line 135, in inner
    dbg.cmdloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py", line 1166, in cmdloop
    cmd.Cmd.cmdloop(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 130, in cmdloop
    line = raw_input(self.prompt)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Still looking for a workaround or a fix, but any input would be welcome to understand the root cause.

Matth

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566398/52598) might be relevant. Do you input a space character from the prompt?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting

Comment: The only place where I have spaces is in the path to the service "exe"

Comment: Is that path coming from a file or a prompt? If it's a file, can you change the encoding of the file to ascii?

Comment: This is run by ansible, through a powershell script

Comment: ansible is python based and through winRM trigger powershell script to setup your windows machine, along the way I'm not sure if the issue is around python or powershell parsing, i have to dig in more for that.