# String in pandas is not printing correctly

Tags: python, string, pandas, encoding

I'm using pandas to load in a csv file containing twitter messages

```
corpus = pd.read_csv(data_path, encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is an example of the data

```
label,date,comment
0,20120528192215Z,"""i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges."""
```

When I try to print the comment I get:

```
print(corpus.iloc[1]['comment'])
>> "i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges."
```

The \xa0 is still in the output.  But if I paste the string from the file and print it, I get the correct output

```
print("""i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges.""")
>> i really don't understand your point.  It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges.
```

I would like to know why the two outputs are different and if there is a way to get the string in pandas to be printed correctly? I would like if there is a better solution then just replace since the data contains many other Unicode representations such as \xe1, \u0111, \u01b0, \u1edd etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Removing \xa0 from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string)

Comment: You want to remove all unicode characters from your column.?

Answer (score 0):

The input data file that pandas loads must be in ASCII.  If it were in UTF-8, the UTF-8 encoder would properly load the UTF-8 bytes.  If the file is not UTF-8, pandas will still load, and the escaped \xa0 will loaded literally and not be translated to the desired unicode non-breaking space.

The reason why it works when you copy/paste is due to python seeing an escape in a string literal.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {u"label": 0, u"date": u"20120528192215Z", u"comment": u"\"i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges.\""}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1], data=data)
df.to_csv("/tmp/corpusutf8.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

```
pd.read_csv("/tmp/corpusutf8.csv")
                                             comment             date  label
0  "i really don't understand your point.  It see...  20120528192215Z      0
df['comment']
1    "i really don't understand your point.  It see...
Name: comment, dtype: object
```

```
file /tmp/corpus.csv
/tmp/corpusutf8.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

If a csv is constructed with the \xa0 and is ascii, Pandas loads as ascii although a utf-8 encoding is specified.

```
cat /tmp/corpusascii.csv
label,date,comment
0,20120528192215Z,"""i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It seems that you are mixing apples and oranges."""
file !$
file /tmp/corpusascii.csv
/tmp/corpusascii.csv: ASCII text
```

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("/tmp/corpusascii.csv", encoding="utf-8")
df1
   label             date                                            comment
0      0  20120528192215Z  "i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It ...
```