# treat '\xa0' as a space in regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am building a web scraper to get data using Selenium and BS4.  I get the html after the page has fully loaded using Selenium.  I then create a BeautifulSoup object using the page_source of the the page opened in Selenium.  After that I start parsing the html to find specific elements on the page.  I need to use regex to parse some strings.  However, some non-breaking spaces (not all) are treated as '\xa0' characters.  This presents a problem with python's regex searches (which don't treat these as spaces).

For example, I have the following string:

```
import re
import unicodedata
testString ="JM Wing\xa0- ...\xa0Transactions of the Royal Society A\xa0..., 2008 - royalsocietypublishing.org"
```

I've tried several of the following solutions, per what I've found online, but none of them seem to work. (Note that the original html.page_source returns a bytes object, so I tried to use decode.

```
testString = testString.replace(u'\xa0', u' ').encode('utf-8') #turns string into bytes
testString = testString.decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore") #must be a bytes object
testString = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", testString)
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get rid of the '\xa0' characters and the regex won't see these as spaces.  Any idea how I might resolve this?  I'd like my soup object to be in utf-8, as I'm potentially dealing with characters from multiple languages. But I really need to turn these into spaces so that I can use regex to parse strings that aren't marked up semantically in html.

EDIT: I can run the following and get the string I want, but the capturing parentheses don't appear to get just the portion I want (and so I get the "-...\ax0" and "," before and after the string).

```
foundString = re.search('-.*([a-zA-Z]*),',testString)[0]
```

this returns "...\xa0Transactions of the Royal Society A\xa0...,".  Ideally, I'd like to only get the words "Transactions...Society" which is what the parentheses should indicate.  Curiously, I can only get this result with re.search().  In contrast, re.findall() just returns an empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Removing \xa0 from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string)

Comment: @CAustin, unfortunately, I've tried the recommendations on that page without luck (note that the 3 main recommendations are the 3 that I listed above)

Answer (score 1):

I sort of figured out a solution.  Since the string that first comes across is html, the spaces in question are actually `&nbsp;`  So, after scraping the html and *before* turning it into soup, I use the following code to replace the `&nbsp;` and then convert it to a byte string.

```
html = html.replace("&nbsp;",' ').encode('utf-8')
```

This seems to get rid of all instances of \xa0 thereafter.

The curious problem is the the capturing parentheses in the regex still aren't functioning and if I use re.findall I get an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
testString = re.sub(r'\s',  ' ', testString)
```

`\xa0` is treated as whitespace in the `\s` set so I believe the above snippet should solve the problem

Comment: Easy and efficient, this should be the accepted answer.