# text processng python to get rid of \r\n\xa0

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe with a column with long text called description. The data from this comes from the jira web instance. I've been trying to get rid of markup in the text using several different methods but none seem to do the trick to remove \r\n\xa0.

Here's what I have so far

```
        df['description'] = df['description'].replace(r'http\S+', '', regex=True).replace(r'www\S+', '', regex=True)
        df['description'] = df['description'].replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', ' ', regex = True)
        df['description'] = df['description'].replace(r'\[(.+)\]\([^\)]+\)', r'\1', regex = True).replace(r'\*\*([^*]+)\*\*', r'\1',                                                                                  regex = True)
        df['description'] = df['description'].replace(r'\*([^*]+)\*',r'\1', regex = True )
        df['description'] = df['description'].astype(str).str.strip()
```

Any ideas what I can do here? sample of text

```
We analyzed found the issue in Garbage Collection which crashed the JVM.\r\n\r\n\xa0\r\n\r\n\xa0\r\n\r\n_Stack: [0x00007f0b58ff1000,0x00007f0b590f1000],\xa0 sp=0x00007f0b590ef120,\xa0 free space=1016k_\r\n\r\n_Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)_\r\n\r\n_V\xa0 [libjvm.so+0x8b9e4f]\xa0 MethodData::clean_extra_data(BoolObjectClosure)+0x1cf_\r\n\r\n_V\xa0 [libjvm.so+0x63c582]\xa0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the text

Comment: added a sample of the text

Comment: Hi,  can you give what would be the expected output from that sample?

Comment: We analyzed the JAVA heap dump and found the issue in Garbage Collection which crashed the JVM.
Stack: [0x00007f0b58ff1000,0x00007f0b590f1000],  sp=0x00007f0b590ef120,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b9e4f]  MethodData::clean_extra_data(BoolObjectClosure*)+0x1cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should capture those if your string isn't `raw`:

```
pattern = r'(\r)|(\n)|(\xa0)'
```

Otherwise, use this:

```
pattern = r'(\\r)|(\\n)|(\\xa0)'
```

Comment: thanks i tried both of what you suggested above - its still not being removed.

Comment: I tried copying the text into another dataframe and then when I apply the 2nd pattern you have , it removes it completely. But I also noticed that when I copy this text, it does not come up with the \xa0 in it. Is this something to do with the xa0? My original text comes from a web application that I am downloading through a rest api

Comment: @TirzaRuth Also, I think between `df['description']` and `.replace()` you should insert `.str`.

Comment: Yes - that was it - needed to be string first, works now, thanks!

Comment: @TirzaRuth you're welcome. i'd appreaciate a vote up and the best answer pick.