# Python read a file that has latin-1 supplement encoding

Tags: python

I am reading a HTML document using Python. It has many characters like `\x93`, `\x94`, `\xa0`. I presume they correspond to latin-1 supplement encoding. Is there a library that deals with this?

Comment: Can you also post the code you are using and the error you are getting?

Comment: maybe you need only `decode('latin1')` or even `open(... ,encoding='latin1')`

Comment: I am not getting any error. When I download the file and read the file in python using ```utf-8``` encoding, and print it, I can see occurences of ```\x93``` etc. I have also tried reading using other encoding schemes

Comment: first show url to file which you downloaded. And show code which you use to download it. Usually HTML pages have information about encoding and you don't have to encode it manulally. Next check in Google in which encoding  chars have codes `\x93`, `\x94`, `\xa0` - and you will know if it is really `latin1` or something else.

Comment: Using Google I found [Python: Removing \xa0 from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string). You should learn to use Google before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply encode and decode strings in latin1 in python: `string.decode('latin1')`

Comment: Hi. Thanks! That seems to work. But I still have occurences of ```\xa0```. By any chance do you know what encoding that comes under?

Comment: @ShrutheeshRamanIyer to answer in what encoding is `\xa0` we would have to use Google - but you could use Google on your own.

Comment: `\xa0` is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also `chr(160)`. You should replace it with space. 

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566398/12181022