# How to remove \xa0 and nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to:

1-import a column of tickers with the number of 88 in excel file

2-get the data of historical price for these list of tickers

3-export the data back to excel

My problem:

```
filename=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.xlsx'

yeah = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='entry')

stock = []

stock = list(yeah['stock_name'])

print(stock)
```

Please check below link of photo shown my error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kizuW.png

**How can I remove all these `\xa0 and nan`? and making it workable for the next step?**

```
symbol_list=[stock]

for symbol in symbol_list:

    symbol_adj_close[symbol] = web.get_data_yahoo([symbol],start,end)['Adj Close']

    print(symbol)
```

Thanks!

Comment: [How to remove \xa0 from string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This line iterates over all elements in `stock` and:

1. Filers out those that are `nan` in panda in `if not pd.isna(s)`.
2. Removes the `\xa0` in `s.replace('\xa0', ' ')`.

```
stock = [ s.replace('\xa0', ' ') for s in stock if not pd.isna(s) ]
```

Comment: @kenneth c Mark if it helped you