# Webscraping result convert to DataFram & remove \xa0

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. I would like to do two things:

1. How to convert the str into Pandas Dataframe?
2. How to remove the Xa0 tag.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILD/profile?p=GILD'

# create a request object, add request header information
request = req.Request(url, headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'
})

with req.urlopen(request) as response:
    data = response.read()

root = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
# print(root)

profile = root.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'Mb(25px)'})

records = []

profile.text
```

And this is the result:

```
'333 Lakeside DriveFoster City, CA 94404United States650-574-`3000http://www.gilead.comSector(s):\xa0HealthcareIndustry:\xa0Drug Manufacturers—GeneralFull Time Employees:\xa011,800'`
```

Comment: Pleas provide the modules you are importing to run this code

Comment: Here is a detailed [StackOverflow post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python#:~:text=%5Cxa0%20is%20actually%20non%2Dbreaking,by%201%20to%204%20bytes.) that talks about getting rid of the '\xa0' tag.

Answer (score -2):

use this to obtein the html from you url the headers you can add later, you need to use requests.get use this fuction in python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError

@author Diego Rojas
def _visit(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  
        if(response.status_code == 200):
            
            return = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except MaxRetryError as Max_err:
        print(f'HTTP error MaxEntry ocurred: {Max_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
```

the question about the tag i dont understand what you want to do

Comment: It is really appreciated that you are trying to help, but it would be better to provide the person writing the question with a full answer. It would have been better to simply comment on their post saying that their intent with the tags was unclear, as our answer here doesn’t provide them with a full explanation.