# Is there any alternative for \ in f string in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, string-formatting, scrapinghub

So I am scraping this website with link : https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/payback-card/
using beautiful soup and python.

```
link = 'https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/payback-card/'
html = urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

details = []

for span in soup.select(".why-amex__subtitle span"):
    details.append(f'{span.get_text(strip=True)}: {span.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True)}')

print(details)
```

**Output:**

```
['EARN POINTS: Earn multiple Points from more than 50 PAYBACK partners2and 2 PAYBACK Points from American\xa0Express PAYBACK Credit\xa0Card for every Rs.\xa0100 spent', 'WELCOME GIFT: Get Flipkart voucher worth Rs. 7503on taking 3 transactions within 60 days of Cardmembership', 'MILESTONE BENEFITS: Flipkart vouchers4worth Rs. 7,000 on spending Rs. 2.5 lacs in a Cardmembership yearYou will earn a Flipkart voucher4worth Rs. 2,000 on spending Rs. 1.25 lacs in a Cardmembership year. Additionally, you will earn a Flipkart voucher4worth Rs. 5,000 on spending Rs. 2.5 lacs in a Cardmembership year.']
```

As you can see in the output there are **\xa0** characters that are to be eliminated from the string.

I tried to use replace function, but it isn't working out with the f string, since there is \ involved.

```
details.append(f'{span.get_text(strip=True)}: {span.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True).replace("\xa0","")}')
```

Is there any alternative to go about this ?

Any help is highly appreciated !!!

Comment: this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python

Comment: Reopening. The supposed duplicate does not work inside an f-string and does not address f-strings.

Comment: @ smitpatel No it does not answer my question, I was seeking a solution with the existing  code using f string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unicodedata` to remove the `\xa0` characters. It will not run when inluded in the f strings, but this will do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from unicodedata import normalize

link = 'https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/payback-card/'
html = urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

details = []

for span in soup.select(".why-amex__subtitle span"):
    a = normalize('NFKD', span.get_text(strip=True))
    b = normalize('NFKD',span.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True))
    details.append(f'{a}: {b}')

print(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be a temporary solution since `.replace("\xa0","")`  not working inside make changes outside before:

```
link = 'https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/payback-card/'
html = urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

details = []

for span in soup.select(".why-amex__subtitle span"):

    element = span.get_text(strip=True).replace("\xa0","")
    next_element = span.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True).replace("\xa0","")
    details.append(f'{element}: {next_element}')

print(details)
```