# unable to remove hex characters from string using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have tried solutions like using encode('ascii', errors='ignore') , but enable to remove these hex characters from string using python. here is my code..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json
import datetime
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe",options=options)
driver.get('https://www.trustradius.com/products/oracle-analytics-cloud/reviews?f=0&o=recent')
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')[-8].string
script = scripts.split('=',1)[1]
for item in script.split("\n"):
    if "searchData" in item:
        item = item.replace('searchData: ','')
        line = item[0:500]
        line = line.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode("utf-8")
        print(line)
```

please let me know if anyone have solution over this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix would be using the below code, if the only improper character is \x20 then replace it with a blank.

```
item = item.replace('\\x20','')
```

I found some answers helpful to similar question in Stackoverflow, please refer it.
[How to remove \xa0 from string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python)

Hope this solution would fix your issue  !!

Comment: using above solution i can replace one character but there are many such hex characters, how to replace them all with their alternative.

Comment: @NiteshRao I have tried many ways like using unicodedata.normalize, re.sub , and using decode and encode seems none of them  work. only thing that worked is replacing with a blank. I am curious to know the objective of this script, in the given website I found some content that contains text like \x20 is the issue related to encoding ? Idk

Comment: @NiteshRao However I am giving some link that deals how to handle the issue please refer the below links https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html ,https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html,https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/470/unicodedata.normalize

Comment: I tried solutions given in above link, but no results. I tried making separate small code and used that item[0:500] string in variable and it is working, IDK why it is not working on above code.