# Weird problem in python with removing \xa0 and other encoding when adding items to list

Tags: python, encoding

I have the following code:

```
x = "$30.00\xa0USD\u202c"
e = x.strip()
print (e)
group = ["a", e.strip(), "b"]
print (group)
```

This is the result it gives me:

```
$30.00 USD‬
['a', '$30.00\xa0USD\u202c', 'b']
```

I want to remove the "\xa0" from the items that I add to the list but .strip() doesn't seem to be working, how do I solve this?

Comment: [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.strip) without parameters returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing whitespaces removed. `\xa0` isn't leading or trailing. Maybe you want to use `replace` instead?

Comment: [how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python) `'\xa0'` is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also chr(160). You should replace it with a space. `string = string.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')`

Answer (score 1):

`strip()` strips whitespace from both sides and there is no whitespace to strip from the string you passed in. It's not clear what you hoped would happen or why; probably the proper solution is to fix whatever produced that string in the first place.

If you want to discard `\xa0` then ... say so.

```py
x = x.replace('\xa0', '')
```

If you want to extract only plain printable ASCII from the string, maybe try a regular expression.

```py
import re
x = ' '.join(re.findall('[ -~]+', x))
```

If you want to strip `\u202c`, you can do that too, of course.

```py
x = x.strip('\u202c\u202f')
```

(I threw in [U+202F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm) too just to show that it's easy to do.)

But again, the unholy mix of raw bytes and Unicode in your input string is likely a sign of corruption earlier in your processing.  If you can fix that, maybe you will no longer need any of these.