# Python how to replace \xa0 with space

Tags: python

I have bytes in which \xao replaces a space. I tried many things to replace it by a space:

```
tmpstr = tmpstr.decode()
```

and then

```
tmpstr = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', tmpstr)
```

or

```
tmpstr = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', tmpstr)
```

or

```
tmpstr = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tmpstr)
```

I also tried:

```
tmpstr = tmpstr.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

or

```
tmpstr = tmpstr.replace('\xa0', ' ')
```

Nothing works. Any idea? and also

```
tmpstr = 'reimbursement\xa0up to 100 Euros per day'
```

```
tmpstr = '{"amount_paid":0,"checked_in":false,"checkin_date":"","checkin_secret":"xxx","data":{"Accomodation":{"Accomodation":"Of your choice booked by yourself (reimbursement\u00a0up to 100 Euros per day)","Additional information":""},"Administration":{"Accomodation 1":"","Accomodation 2":"","Accomodation price 1":"","Accomodation price 2":"","Date of birth":"","From 2":"","Membership":"Accepted","Nationality":"","Notes":"","Other reimbursements":"","Phone number":"","To 2":"","Transport reimbursement":""},"Financial help for travel":{"Apply for reimbursement":"No","Could you please elaborate a bit upon the reasons why ?":"","What would be the estimated amount of the travel reimbursement you would need ?":""},"Participation mode":{"From":"31/10/2021","How do you plan to participate?":"In person","To":"13/11/2021"},"Personal Data":{"Affiliation":"xxx","Country":"Italy","Email Address":"xxx","Expertise and topic of research":"xxx","First Name":"xxx","Gender":"Male","I do not want my name and email address to be kept and used by the Institut Pascal for future mailings for and/or by the Institut Pascal":"No","I do not want my pictures to be published on the IPa website and social networks":"No","Last Name":"xxx","Position":"PostDoc","Reason that you are interested in participating in this program":"xxx","Special Requirements":"xxx","Would you need an official invitation for visa-purposes ?":"No"}},"event_id":xxx,"full_name":"xxx","paid":false,"personal_data":{"affiliation":"xxx","country":"xxx","email":"xxx","firstName":"xxx","phone":"","position":"xxx","surname":"xxx","title":"Male"},"price":0,"registrant_id":"11349","registration_date":"2021-07-10T22:08:12.380610+00:00","ticket_price":0}'
```

Thanks

Comment: `tmpstr.strip()` ? or how about using `tmpstr = re.sub('\xa0', '', tmpstr)`

Comment: are u working with json or nested dictionaries or something like that?

Comment: It's not working but thank you

Comment: I also tried `tmpstr = re.sub('\xa0', '', tmpstr)` and it's not working I work with json

Comment: i have the same problem with nested dictionaries, don't know whats the problem still :( sry

Comment: Can you provide with the string on which you are working on?

Comment: Of your choice booked by yourself (reimbursement\xa0up to 100 Euros per day)

Comment: it is the value of a form field to which participants have responded. I am using this form for event registrations and am having this problem only for one event I really don't understand.

Comment: The second solution with `replace` works for me in my python console.

Comment: I did edit my question and paste the entire string

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing your string from a regular expression like below

```
[0-9a-zA-Z \.\-_{add more special characters}]*
```

1. * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2. 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
3. a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
4. A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
5. "space"  matches the character   with index 3210 (2016 or 408) literally (case sensitive)
6. . matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
7. - matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
8. _ matches the character _ with index 9510 (5F16 or 1378) literally (case sensitive)

**You can paste your string [here](https://regex101.com/r/yiz2Vq/1) and see if this works for you before implementing in code**

You can also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42904357/12064319). It is the opposite of mine. This answer is removing \x chars using regex.

Example python code

```
import re

text = "reimbursement\xa0up to 100 Euros per day"
pattern = r'[0-9a-zA-Z\.\-_]*'

print(" ".join([i.strip() for i in re.findall(pattern, text)]))

# -----------------------------------------------

print(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', ' ', text).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').strip())
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't understand your answer. Could you give me an example in python please ?

Comment: I have edited please see if works and tell me!

Comment: Thank You very much ! It's not working. Here's the entire string :

Comment: I couldn't add the string in the comment so I did edit my question with the entire string

Comment: I did `tmpstr = tmpstr.replace(u'\\u00a0', u' ')` and it's working. I dont know why \\u00a0 became \xa0

Comment: `u' '` is \xa0 itself you replacing `u'\\u00a0'` with `u' '`