# Character list replacing weird output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im reading data from a csv file, here a snippet of the output.

```
['movie_title', 'director_name', 'duration', 'gross', 'genres', 'actor_1_name', 'actor_2_name', 'actor_3_name', 'facenumber_in_poster', 'plot_keywords', 'language', 'country', 'content_rating', 'budget', 'title_year', 'imdb_score', 'movie_facebook_likes,AvatarÂ\xa0', 'James Cameron', '178', '760505847', 'Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi', 'CCH Pounder', 'Joel David Moore', 'Wes Studi']
```

There is the `'\n'` that im trying to get rid of and the `'Â\xa0'` in every one of the movie titles, heres what ive tried with the failed output.

```
split2 = [elem.replace('\n', ',') for elem in split2]
```

with output `'movie_facebook_likes,AvatarÂ\xa0'`, which successfully gets rid of `\n` but now the list qoutations are messed up.

```
split2 = [elem.replace('\n', "','") for elem in split2]
```

with output
`"movie_facebook_likes','AvatarÂ\xa0"`,

fixes the last problem but now the wrong type of quotations are there, does anyone have a suggestion, im honestly stumped. Im just trying to get `\n` out of the way then i can work on `Â\xa0` later.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python

Comment: I don't see any '\n' in there. And why are you trying to fix the bad list with additional code instead of fixing the code that produced the bad list?

Comment: Because this is a csv file that our prof gave us with 5000+ lines just like this. I cant mutate the csv file as he will take marks off. I gave the wrong output code regarding the \n, the original output as follows: '6.8', '85000\nThe Dark Knight RisesÂ\xa0', 'Christopher Nolan',

Comment: So the prof gave you a csv file. Not a Python list. So there can still be a flaw in whatever code you wrote to turn the csv file into a Python list. We can't tell because you neither showed the file nor that code. Also, if it *is* a problem not in your code but in the csv file, then, unless the point of the exercise is to handle the badness of the file, I'd *tell* the prof about the badness so that *they* can fix it.

Comment: I mean the first sentence of the post was that I was reading a csv file. Thanks.

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: aNd YoUr pOiNt iS

Answer (score -1):

Your code makes no sense at all. However, try this out:

```
splitted_list = [s.replace('\n','').replace('AvatarÂ\xa0,'') for s in <whatever it is>]
```

This code basically replaces both '\n' and the other Avatar thing with ''. This will give you your desired output.
Tip: Don't spam variables with same names, especially for .replace()