# Missing values in certain cells when scraping data from website using Beautifulsoup in Python and placing it in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have scraped data from a website using Beautifulsoup, and I want to place it into a Pandas DataFrame and then write it to a file. Most of the data is being written to the file as expected, but some cells are missing values. For example, the first row of the Phone number column is missing a value. The 39th, 45th, and 75th rows of the Postal code column are missing values. Not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

schools = "https://www.winnipegsd.ca/page/9258/school-directory-a-z"
page = urlopen(schools)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,features="html.parser")

table_ = soup.find('table')

Name=[]
Address=[]
PostalCode=[]
Phone=[]
Grades=[]
Website=[]
City=[]
Province=[]

for row in table_.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==6:
        Name.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        Address.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        PostalCode.append(cells[4].find(text=True).next_element.getText())
        Phone.append(cells[5].find(text=True).replace('T: ',''))
        Grades.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        Website.append('https://www.winnipegsd.ca'+cells[1].findAll('a')[0]['href'])


df = pd.DataFrame(Name,columns=['Name'])
df['Street Address']=Address
df['Postal Code']=PostalCode
df['Phone Number']=Phone
df['Grades']=Grades
df['Website']=Website

df.to_csv("file.tsv", sep = "\t",index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pd.read_html()` to extract data from table. Then you can do basic `.str` manipulation:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


schools = "https://www.winnipegsd.ca/page/9258/school-directory-a-z"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(schools).content, "html.parser")

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
df = df.dropna(how="all", axis=0).drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 3"])
df["Contact"] = (
    df["Contact"]
    .str.replace(r"T:\s*", "", regex=True)
    .str.replace("School Contact Information", "")
    .str.strip()
)
df["Postal Code"] = df["Address"].str.extract(r"(.{3} .{3})$")
df["Website"] = [
    f'https://www.winnipegsd.ca{a["href"]}'
    if "http" not in a["href"]
    else a["href"]
    for a in soup.select("tbody td:nth-child(2) a")
]

print(df.head(10))
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                             School Name Grades                     Address       Contact Postal Code                                            Website
0               Adolescent Parent Centre   9-12       136 Cecil St. R3E 2Y9  204-775-5440     R3E 2Y9  https://www.winnipegsd.ca/AdolescentParentCentre/
1            Andrew Mynarski V.C. School    7-9   1111 Machray Ave. R2X 1H6  204-586-8497     R2X 1H6          https://www.winnipegsd.ca/AndrewMynarski/
2         Argyle Alternative High School  10-12       30 Argyle St. R3B 0H4  204-942-4326     R3B 0H4                  https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Argyle/
3                   Brock Corydon School    N-6   1510 Corydon Ave. R3N 0J6  204-488-4422     R3N 0J6            https://www.winnipegsd.ca/BrockCorydon/
4                       Carpathia School    N-6   300 Carpathia Rd. R3N 1T3  204-488-4514     R3N 1T3               https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Carpathia/
5                       Champlain School    N-6     275 Church Ave. R2W 1B9  204-586-5139     R2W 1B9               https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Champlain/
6      Children of the Earth High School   9-12      100 Salter St. R2W 5M1  204-589-6383     R2W 5M1      https://www.winnipegsd.ca/ChildrenOfTheEarth/
7          Collège Churchill High School   7-12         510 Hay St. R3L 2L6  204-474-1301     R3L 2L6               https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Churchill/
8                         Clifton School    N-6    1070 Clifton St. R3E 2T7  204-783-7792     R3E 2T7                 https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Clifton/
10  Daniel McIntyre Collegiate Institute   9-12  720 Alverstone St. R3E 2H1  204-783-7131     R3E 2H1          https://www.winnipegsd.ca/DanielMcintyre/
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: For the phone number you can do: `df['Contact'] = df['Contact'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})')`

Comment: Thanks, this works as intended. But I would still like to know why my original method had missing values. I would like to see if I can adjust it so that it works, but first I need to understand the reason for the missing values.

Comment: I'd also adjust the `Address` entry: `df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.slice(stop=-8)` or `df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(.*)(?=\s.{3} .{3}$)')` to get just the address here, without the postal code. (Mind you, do this *after* this line: `df["Postal Code"] = df["Address"].str.extract(r"(.{3} .{3})$")`).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting some missing data value. Becaue they didn't exist in the original/source HTML DOM/table. So if you didn't check then you will get `NoneType` error and the program will break but you can easily get rid of meaning fix them using `if else None` statemnt. The following code should work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

schools = "https://www.winnipegsd.ca/page/9258/school-directory-a-z"
page = requests.get(schools).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
data =[]
for row in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
    Name = row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableOddCol-6:nth-child(2)')
    Name = Name.a.text if Name else None
    #print(Name)
    Address= row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-6:nth-child(5)')
    Address = Address.get_text() if Address else None 
    #print(Address)
    PostalCode=row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-6:nth-child(5)')
    PostalCode = PostalCode.get_text().split('.')[-1] if PostalCode else None
    #print(PostalCode)
    Phone = row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableOddCol-6:nth-child(6)')
    Phone = Phone.get_text().split('School')[-2].replace('T:','') if Phone else None
    #print(Phone)
    Grades= row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-6:nth-child(3)')
    Grades = Grades.get_text() if Grades else None
    #print(Grades)
    Website= row.select_one('td.ms-rteTableOddCol-6:nth-child(2)')
    Website= 'https://www.winnipegsd.ca'+ Website.a.get('href') if Website else None
    #print(Website)
    data.append({
        'Name':Name,
        'Address':Address,
        'PostalCode':PostalCode,
        'Phone':Phone,
        'Grades':Grades,
        'Website':Website
        })

df=pd.DataFrame(data).dropna(how='all')
print(df)

#df.to_csv("file.tsv", sep = "\t",index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
          Name  ...                                            Website
1          Adolescent Parent Centre  ...  https://www.winnipegsd.ca/AdolescentParentCentre/
2       Andrew Mynarski V.C. School  ...          https://www.winnipegsd.ca/AndrewMynarski/
3    Argyle Alternative High School  ...                  https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Argyle/
4              Brock Corydon School  ...            https://www.winnipegsd.ca/BrockCorydon/
5                  Carpathia School  ...               https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Carpathia/
..                              ...  ...                                                ...
84                    Weston School  ...                  https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Weston/
85             William Whyte School  ...            https://www.winnipegsd.ca/WilliamWhyte/
86  Winnipeg Adult Education Centre  ...   https://www.winnipegsd.ca/WinnipegAdultEdCentre/
87                  Wolseley School  ...                https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Wolseley/
88               WSD Virtual School  ...                 https://www.winnipegsd.ca/Virtual/

[79 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695179/18470692) by @AndrejKesely is definitely a more pythonic way to handle this case, but you mention in the comments that you are still interested as to why your original method had missing values. Justifiably so! This is where learning how to code should start: by trying to understand why code is failing, well before moving on to a *refactored* solution.

**1. The phone numbers**

Let's make some prints:

```
for row in table_.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==6:
        # ...
        # Phone.append(cells[5].find(text=True).replace('T: ',''))
        # ...
        print(cells[5].findAll(text=True))

['T:\xa0', '204-775-5440', '\xa0\xa0', 'School Contact Information']
['T: 204-586-8497', '\xa0\xa0', 'School Contact Information', '\xa0']
```

The problem here is inconsistency in the source code. Open up Chrome DevTools with `Ctrl + Shift + J`, right click on any of the phone numbers, and select `inspect`. You'll move into the "Elements" tab and see how the `html` is set up. E.g. first two numbers:

```
ph_no1 = """
<div>
 <span>T:&nbsp;</span>
 <span lang="EN">204-775-5440
  <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div> ... School Contact Information </div>
"""

ph_no2 = """
<div>
 <span lang="FR-CA">T: 204-586-8497
  <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div> ... School Contact Information </div>
"""
```

The aforementioned prints with `findAll` get you the texts from each `span` consecutively. I've only shown the first two here, but that's enough to see why you get different data back. So, the problem with the first entry of numbers is that `cells[5].find(text=True).replace('T: ','')` is only getting us the *first* text snippet and in the case of `ph_no1` this is `'T:\xa0'`. For the reason why the `replace` cannot handle this, see e.g. this  [`SO post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/how-to-remove-xa0-from-string-in-python).

As it happens, a couple of phone numbers were problematic:

```
df['Phone Number'][df['Phone Number']\
                   .str.extract(r'(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})')[0]\
                       .to_numpy()!=df['Phone Number'].to_numpy()]

0                T: 
32    204-783-9012  # 2 extra spaces
33    204-474-1492  # 2 extra spaces
38    204-452-5015  # 2 extra spaces
```

Suggested solution for the phone numbers. Instead of your code, try getting all the text and extracting a regex pattern that matches the number using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

```
import re

Phone.append(re.search(r'(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})',cells[5].get_text()).group())
# e.g. \d{3}- means 3 digits followed by "-" etc.
```

**2. The postal code**

Problem here is basically the same. Here's an irregular postal code (39th entry), followed by a "regular" one;

```
pc_error = """
<div>
 <span>290 Lilac St.&nbsp;</span>
 <br>R3M 2T5
</div>
"""

regular_pc = """
<div>
 <span>960 Wolseley Ave.&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div>
 <span>R3G 1E7
 </span>
</div>
"""
```

You wrote:

```
Address.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
PostalCode.append(cells[4].find(text=True).next_element.getText())
```

But as you can see above, it turns out that the first example does not actually have a `next_element`. Now, if you try:

```
print(len(cells[4].findAll(text=True)))
```

You'll find that, regardless of the elements, the entire text of each cell will in fact be captured as a list of two strings (`['address','postal code']`). E.g.:

```
['511 Clifton St.\xa0', 'R3G 2X3']
['136 Cecil St.\xa0', 'R3E 2Y9']
```

So, in this particular case, we could simply write:

```
Address.append(cells[4].findAll(text=True)[0].strip()) # 1st elem and strip
PostalCode.append(cells[4].findAll(text=True)[1].strip()) # 2nd elem and strip
```

(or again do `.get_text()` and use a regex pattern; as done by @AndrejKesely).

Hope this helps a bit in clearing up the issues, and suggesting some methods of how to spot unexpected behaviour (prints are always a good friend!).