# Remove ASCII control characters from text file Python

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7, ascii

I have a text file from which I have to read a lot of numbers (double). 
It has ASCII control characters like DLE, NUL etc. which are visible in the text file. so
when I read them to get only the doubles/ints from a line, I am getting erros like "invalid literals \x10". Shown below are the first 2 lines of my file.

```
DLE NUL NUL NUL [1, 167, 133, 6]DLE NUL NUL   
YS FS NUL[0.0, 4.3025989e-07, 1.5446712e-06, 3.1393029e-06, 5.0430463e-06, 7.1382601e-06
```

How do I remove all these control characters from a text file at once, using Python?  I want
this to be done before I parse the file into numbers ...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you should consider parsing them instead so that you know how to parse the rest of the file.

Comment: However, I still really need to remove these characters before I do any sort of reading with them....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [string.printable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string#string.printable).

```
>>> import string
>>> filter(string.printable.__contains__, '\x00\x01XYZ\x00\x10')
'XYZ'
```

Comment: Using regex (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/93029/1988505)) is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh, If speed matters, you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: @alvas, How about using `unicode(string.printable)` if you want to use exactly same characters?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is very old post, but I am answering as I think, it could help others.

I did as follows. It will replace all ASCII control characters by an empty string.

```
line = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1F]+', '', line)
```

[Ref: ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) Code](http://www.december.com/html/spec/asciiall.html)

[Ref: Python re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)