# Python 3 and Unicode - How do I print newlines (general problems understanding this)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have sifted through lots and lots of python/unicode explanations but I just can't seem to make sense of this.

Here is the situation:

I am pulling loads of comments off reddit (making a bot) and would like to primarily store them in a MongoDB, but also need to be able to print out comment trees in order to manually check what's going on.

I have had no problems so far putting comments into the DB, but when I try to print to stdout the CP1252 charset is having trouble with characters that it obviously doesn't support.

As I have read, in Python 3 everything internally (strings) are stored as Unicode, it's the input and output which must be bytes, so this is fine - I can encode the unicode to CP1252 and in a couple of situations I will see \x** characters which I don't mind - I am guessing they represent out of range characters?

The problem is I was printing out comment trees (to stdout) using \n (linefeeds) and tabs so it was easy to look over, but apparently when you encode a unicode string with newline escape sequences it escapes *them* so they get printed as literals.

For reference here is my encode statement:

```
encoded = post.tree_to_string().encode('cp1252','ignore')
```

Thanks

EDIT:

What I want is

```
|Parent Comment

    |Child comment 1

        |GChild comment 1

    |Child comment 2

|Parent Comment 2
```

What I get is

```
b"\n|Parent comment \n\n |Child comment \n\n etc
```

Comment: Are your really `print`ing the strings, your are you just looking at the string at the python prompt?

Comment: I want to be able to print them to a file/stdout so I can manually look over them - see example I am now putting in main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing to the console, Python will automatically encode strings in the console's encoding (`cp437` on US Windows) and raise an exception for any character that the console encoding does not support.  for example:

```
#!python3
#coding: utf8
print('Some text\nwith Chinese 美国\ncp1252 ÀÁÂÃ\nand cp437 ░▒▓')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print('Some text\nwith Chinese \u7f8e\u56fd\ncp1252 \xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\nand cp437 ░▒▓')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 24-25: character maps to <undefined>
```

To change this default, you can alter `stdout` to explicitly specify the encoding and how to handle errors:

```
#!python3
#coding: utf8
import io,sys
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding=sys.stdout.encoding,errors='replace')
print('Some text\nwith Chinese 美国\ncp1252 ÀÁÂÃ\nand cp437 ░▒▓')
```

Output (to a cp437 console):

```
Some text
with Chinese ??
cp1252 ????
and cp437 ░▒▓
```

You can also do this explicitly without altering `stdout`, by writing directly to its `buffer` interface:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write('Some text\nwith Chinese 美国\ncp1252 ÀÁÂÃ\nand cp437 ░▒▓'.encode('cp437',errors='replace'))
```

A third alternative is to set the following environment variable before starting Python, which will alter `stdout` similar to the `TextIOWrapper` solution:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=cp437:replace
```

Finally, since you mentioned also writing to a file, the easiest way to see all the characters you are writing is to use UTF-8 as the encoding to a file:

```
#!python3
#coding: utf8
with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('Some text\nwith Chinese 美国\ncp1252 ÀÁÂÃ\nand cp437 ░▒▓')
```

Comment: That last section of code actually got it to write to a file with the format I wanted so thanks. It is strange that I can't get it to write to stdout but I need to understand the subject better. In the meantime this will do for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but couldn't you just remove newlines and tabs before printing to stdout?

```
print(re.sub('[\t\n]', ' ', post.tree_to_string()))
```

You could also tell Python to remove all control chars, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93029/778272).

Comment: I need the newlines for formatting - the tree_to_string gives a nice view of comments with spacing between them and indenting - so I want stdout to leave the newlines in place of '\n' but it does not parse them as linefeeds - I guess they are escaped?

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT need encode stings to bytes for printing in python3，just make your stdout(console) an unicode environment...

print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Comment: I have heard this is bad practice? I will try this if I cannot find anything else though.