# Insert invisible unicode into MySQL using python3 but encountered duplicate

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

When I insert the device data into MySQL(v5.5.6) using python(v3.2). It encountered a problem.

This is device A (It contains three unicode and a blank space):
***'\u202d\u202d \u202d'***

And device B (It is only a blank space):
***' '***

The problem is when i insert all device data into MySQL , Error is

***Duplicate entry 'activate_device-20151201-1-5740-01000P---‭‭ ‭--' for key 'PRIMARY'***

I guess MySQL has deal the '\u202d'(A unicode to reverse string maybe?).

How can I simulate the process in python3 like MySQL?
How can I avoid the duplicate?

The expected result is translate '\u202d\u202d \u202d' to ' ' in python3.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you expecting some Middle Eastern text -- "right-to-left"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ambiguities here. Do you want to keep only the visible ascii characters or also visible unicode characters ?

If you want to keep only visible ascii characters, the simple way is to use the python inbuilt `string` module.

```
import string
new_string = "".join(filter(lambda x:x in string.printable, original_string))
```

For your specific usecase, a space is part of visible ascii - so the above will convert '\u202d\u202d \u202d' and ' ' to ' '

Comment: That's a bit more complicated. Here is a good explanation on how to do that using regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python