# How to delete non-printable character in rdd using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Need to remove non-printable characters from rdd.

Sample data is below

```
"@TSX•","None"
"@MJU•","None"
```

expected output

```
@TSX,None
@MJU,None
```

Tried below code but its not working

```
sqlContext.read.option("sep", ","). \
                option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1"). \
                option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").csv(<path>).rdd.map(lambda s: s.replace("\xe2",""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textFile` function of `sparkContext` and use `string.printable` to *remove all special characters from strings*.

```
import string
sc.textFile(inputPath to csv file)\
    .map(lambda x: ','.join([''.join(e for e in y if e in string.printable).strip('\"') for y in x.split(',')]))\
    .saveAsTextFile(output path )
```

**Explanation**

For your input line `"@TSX•","None"`
`for y in x.split(',')` *splits the string line* to `["@TSX•", "None"]` where `y` *represent each elements in the array while iterating*
`for e in y if e in string.printable` is *checking each character* in `y` is *printable or not* 
*if printable then* the *characters are joined to form a string of printable characters*
`.strip('\"')` *removes the preceding and ending inverted commas from the printable string*
finally the *list of Strings is converted to comma sepated string* by `','.join([''.join(e for e in y if e in string.printable).strip('\"') for y in x.split(',')])`

I hope the explanation is clear enough to understand

Comment: code is working but here i need to remove only non printable characters, i need special characters in this data. is there a way to do it?

Comment: ERROR: .map(lambda x: ','.join([filter(lambda e: e in string.printable, y) for y in x.split(',')]))\
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, filter found

Comment: Not working getting below output: <filter object at 0x030B03B0>,<filter object at 0x030B0330>

Comment: Its working perfectly fine :) can you please elaborate your code. it will be easy for me to understand each and every part

Comment: I have explained as much as I could @LUZO

Comment: Hello @RameshMaharjan, do you have similar approach in scala. My day is exhausted finding it but no benefit. Thanks.

Comment: @KanavSharma in scala you can simply do `sc.textFile(input path ).map(_.split(",").map(x => x.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")).mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(output path )` what it does is replace all non-ascii characters with empty and replace the beginning and ending inverted comma . Hope its helpful and you can upvote the answer if its helpful

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, thanks. but what happens is that my unwanted character is being treated by spark as a newline character. So once I read the file using spark via creating rdds or dataframes, it is omitted by the replaceall function.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to try to filter your text using `string.printable`:

```python
import string
sqlContext.read\
    .option("sep", ",")\
    .option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")\
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
    .csv(<path>)\
    .rdd\
    .map(lambda s: filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s))
```

**Example**

```python
import string
rdd = sc.parallelize(["TSX•,None","MJU•,None", "!@#ABC,*()XYZ"])

print(rdd.map(lambda s: filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)).collect())
#['TSX,None', 'MJU,None', '!@#ABC,*()XYZ']
```

**References**

- [Stripping non printable characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I dont want to remove special characters. Is there a way ?

Comment: @LUZO this solution **doesn't** remove special characters. `string.printable` includes all characters that can be printed. The `filter` statement removes only characters that are not found in `string.printable`. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @LUZO I have updated the example I provided to show that special characters are retained with this solution.

Comment: I have tried your code. i am getting mentioned error : AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>'

Comment: That seems unrelated to the non-printable characters issue. I suspect that there's more code you're using that you're not sharing. Can you post edit the question and add the full code?

Comment: i have edited the sample data. i just want to remove non printable so i didnt included everything