# Center selection of center text widget python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, select, text, widget

I have a text widget

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text_box = tk.Text(root)
text_box.pack()

text_box.tag_config("tag-center", justify="center")
text_box.insert("end", "22", "tag-center")

root.mainloop()
```

but when I select I have this

[image]

but I want select only text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripping non printable characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92438/stripping-non-printable-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @Don'tAccept That isn't OP's question. Their problem is that when you select text in a `tkinter.Text`, it doesn't only select the text. This happens when the text is centered.

Comment: So what me doing

Comment: This question requires clarification. You just don't like the look of the widget when you select text?