# Python: Extract text from multiple pdf and paste on excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf

i'm a total new in python, could you help me correct this code?

I would like to add 2 things:

1. do the operation on multiple pdf and not just one and pasting the content in A2,A3 A4 and so on
2. if possible writing in the another row (B2,B3,B4) the name of the pdf file.

Thank you in advance, this is the code i'm working with

```
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl
pdfFileObj = open("file.pdf", 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
mytext = pageObj.extractText()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'
sheet['A1'] = mytext

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
print('DONE!!')
```

I've modified the code as suggested and the cycle seems to get all the pages! but maybe i have to work with "sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(output)" because it seems to print a lot of spaces

```
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl
import os
import glob
root_dir = "your directory"

filenames = []
# root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/)
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/**', recursive=True):
    if filename.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
        filenames.append(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')#your file excel
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'

for row, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
        count=pdfReader.numPages
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        mytext = pageObj.extractText()
        for i in range(count): 
            page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            output = []
            output = page.extractText() 
            print(output)

    sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(output)
    sheet[f'B{row}'].value = filename

wb.save('excel.xlsx') #your file excel
print('DONE!!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to put the code you wrote which reads the pdf file into a `for` loop which iterates over the filenames (in this case, the filenames are stored as a `tuple`).

Using `enumerate`, `row` increments every iteration of the loop, and starts at 1. So the text and filename will be put into A1 and B1, then A2 and B2, and so on.

```py
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl

filenames = ("file.pdf", 
             "file2.pdf", 
             "file3.pdf", 
            )

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'

for row, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
        pdfReader.numPages
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        mytext = pageObj.extractText()
    
    sheet[f'A{row}'].value = mytext
    sheet[f'B{row}'].value = filename

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
print('DONE!!')
```

---

You can get a list of all the filenames ending in `.pdf` quite easily by iterating over all the files in a directory, and checking if the filename ends in `.pdf`. If it does, use `os.path.join` to give you the full filepath, and append it to the `filenames` list.

You could also use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module, too.

```py
import os

filenames = []
directory = r"C:\Stuff\PDF Files"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.lower().endswith(".pdf"):
        filenames.append(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

---

Updated code:

```py
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl
import os
import glob
import re
import itertools

# Used to strip characters that can't be written to a spreadsheet
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/93029/3589122
control_chars = ''.join(map(chr, itertools.chain(range(0x00,0x20), range(0x7f,0xa0))))
control_char_re = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))

def remove_control_chars(s):
    return control_char_re.sub('', s)

root_dir = 'your directory' # root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/)

filenames = (filename for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '/**/*.pdf', recursive=True))

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx') # your file excel
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'

row = 1
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        try:
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
            count = pdfReader.numPages
            
            output = []
            for i in range(count): 
                print(i, filename)
                page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
                output.append(page.extractText())
                #print(output)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: PyPDF2 could not read {filename}. Continuing... ({e})')
            continue
    
    sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(remove_control_chars(output))
    sheet[f'B{row}'].value = filename
    row += 1

wb.save('excel.xlsx') #your file excel
print('DONE!!')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer GordonAitchJay, there is a way to "automatically" take all pdfs in a folder without having to name them? something like *pdf to say everything that ends with pdf? This is why i wanted also to add the name of the file in another column

Comment: You best believe it! See updated answer.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me!
But the script return an empy file, if i print what's in mytext I see a part of the copied text so probably the problem is when trying to writing it down to excel?

Comment: That's strange. I just tried it now, and it works for me. Try appending `.value` to `sheet[f'A{row}']` and `sheet[f'B{row}']`, so it's like `sheet[f'A{row}'].value`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sadly no, it doesnt paste anything i dont understand why the code i pasted work and why yours which is way better does not paste anything!

Comment: Maybe is something related to the second part of the code? i dont use filenames = ("file.pdf",  "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf",  ) anymore because i'm using your second part of the script for saving them

Comment: I edited my answer with the 2 bits of code combined. It worked for me. Just change the value of `directory`.

Comment: worked like a charm!
I dont want to bother you anymore so feel free not to answer :) 
I'm working on 2 things, glob as suggested (to take more pdf in subdirectories) and more important taking more page of the pdf. 
So what i'm trying is adding something like this    
 for i in range(count):
        page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
        output.append(page.extractText())
    print(output)

Comment: No worries. Yeah that approach seems good - put all the text into a list. You could then chuck it in 1 cell with `sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(output)` or put each page in separate columns or rows.

Comment: Thanks again! the for cycle worked and now the script gets all the pages. The strange effect is that in excel now every letter seems to have a spacing, so everything it's in vertical

Comment: Okay, so if you did `'\n'.join(output)`, `output` here is supposed to be a `list` of strings (pages of text), but for you it's a `str`, so it's adding a newline between every character, instead of between every page of text.

Comment: what do you suggest? also because thank to you i've modified again my script to catch all the pdf in subdirectories (glob worked perfeclty so thanks again) but if i try to process more than 6-7 pdf at once the notebook raise this error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'. And it happens only if I try with more than 6 pdf ad once strange no?

I'll edit my first post with the new script

Comment: You need to move `output = []` outside of (just above) the loop `for i in range(count):`, then change `output = page.extractText()` to `output.append(page.extractText())`. As it currently is, only the last page of text is saved. You can use `glob` to directly filter `.pdf` files, instead of doing it manually with the `if` statement. Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with more than 6/7 files? i get this error with 7 pdf

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-07fb0aa603b8> in <module>
     23         for i in range(count):
     24             page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
---> 25             output.append(page.extractText())
     26             print(output)
     27 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py in extractText(self, Tj_sep, TJ_sep)
   1283         """
   1284         deprecate_with_replacement("extractText", "extract_text")
-> 1285         return self.extract_text(Tj_sep=Tj_sep, TJ_sep=TJ_sep)
   1286 
   1287     mediabox = _create_rectangle_accessor(PG.MEDIABOX, ())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py in extract_text(self, Tj_sep, TJ_sep, space_width)
   1261         :return: a string object.
   1262         """
-> 1263         return self._extract_text(self, self.pdf, space_width, PG.CONTENTS)
   1264 
   1265     def extract_xform_text(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py in _extract_text(self, obj, pdf, space_width, content_key)
   1243                     text = ""
   1244             else:
-> 1245                 process_operation(operator, operands)
   1246         output += text  # just in case of
   1247         return output

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py in process_operation(operator, operands)
   1195                 tm_matrix[5] -= TL
   1196             elif operator == b"Tj":
-> 1197                 text += operands[0].translate(cmap)
   1198             else:
   1199                 return None

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

Comment: That's caused by a particular file (i.e. the 6th file). `PyPDF2` is unable to extract the text, possible because the pdf file is corrupt, or because there is a bug in PyPDF2. Maybe try updating `PyPDF2`, or try another pdf library such as `PyMuPDF` - https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage.html#TextPage.extractText

Comment: Failing that, you can just ignore the error with a try-except statement.

Comment: I inserted the try-except statement as suggested but it just stops after the first 6-7 file 
(try:
    for row, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
            count = pdfReader.numPages
            output = []
        for i in range(count): 
            page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            output.append(page.extractText())
            print(output)
except Exception: 
    pass

So i'll try with PyMuPDF but the syntax seems very different

Comment: So PyPDF2 cannot read the 6th or 7th file. Is this file corrupt? Can you view the pdf in another application? Nevertheless, because you had the entire loop inside the `try` block, when an exception was raised, it completely exited the loop. That's why it stops after the 6th or 7th file. You should only include the line of code that raises the exception inside the `try` block. I've edited my answer, try that. Note I had to remove `enumerate` and manually set and update `row`, otherwise there would be a gap in the spreadsheet each time PyPDF2 can't read a file.

Comment: Thanks for help as always.
I've tried removing the 5th or 6th or 7th file but still the same error even with the try except (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'). Maybe when it reach a certain level of text or \n's it stops?

Comment: No problemo. So I tried it myself on 150 random pdf files I had and PyPDF2 failed to read some, and in some cases `extractText()` returns characters that can't be written to a spreadsheet. See my updated answer.

Comment: It raises a new kind of error : # root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/) (which it is i'll paste it there ("C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Testscript")
Until now I just pointed to a folder on desktop which used to work.

Does this means the pdf files should be in the same directory of python?

Comment: Post the full traceback. No, the pdf files just need to be in root_dir or a subdirectory.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f7c745c7b7c1> in <module>
     39             continue
     40 
---> 41     sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(remove_control_chars(output))
     42     sheet[f'B{row}'].value = filename
     43     row += 1

<ipython-input-11-f7c745c7b7c1> in remove_control_chars(s)
     12 
     13 def remove_control_chars(s):
---> 14     return control_char_re.sub('', s)
     15 
     16 root_dir = "C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Testscript" # root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: it seems to try to open the same file :
0 C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Testscript/90300_assignsubmission_file_\Infa_210518.pdf
1 C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Testscript/90300_assignsubmission_file_\Infa_210518.pdf
2 C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Testscript/I90300_assignsubmission_file_\Infa_210518.pdf

Comment: Sorry, that error was my fault because I put the call to `remove_control_chars` in the wrong place. Change this line: `sheet[f'A{row}'].value = '\n'.join(remove_control_chars(output))` to this: `sheet[f'A{row}'].value = remove_control_chars('\n'.join(output))`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It opens the file once, and extracts the text for each page one at a time. The print statement prints the page number (starting at 0) and filename every new page.

Comment: You are my hero and saviour! everything worked perfectly! I really envy your ability. I don't know how to thank you for the time you dedicated helping me

Comment: haha it was quite the journey wasn't it? I'm just happy to help. Cheers