# What is '\u200d1500'?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, integer

I crawled data from a website which was in string format I replaced string character and now data only contains number. But when I want to convert this column to numeric I get that error. I have two columns which first is previous_prices other is now_prices. If now the product is not on sale program fill nas with previous_prices. Previous_prices type is int64, now_prices type is object. Error is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\u200d1500'.

Actually I saw a similiar question but that question is not relevant to '\u200d1500'.

| now_prices_after_fillna |
| --- |
| 1450 |
| ‍1500 |
| 700 |
| 1700 |
| 2090 |

There are strange situation when When I change now_prices to integer and then fill na with previous_prices general data type was int. But when I want to export that data to excel I get this error. I can not understand problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\u200d` is not printable character, here is solution for remove it and converting to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'now_prices_after_fillna':['1450', u'\u200d1500']})
    
print (df)
  now_prices_after_fillna
0                    1450
1                   ‍1500

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451873/2901002
import sys

# build a table mapping all non-printable characters to None
NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE = {
    i: None for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode + 1) if not chr(i).isprintable()
}

def make_printable(s):
    """Replace non-printable characters in a string."""

    # the translate method on str removes characters
    # that map to None from the string
    return s.translate(NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE)


df['now_prices_after_fillna'] = (df['now_prices_after_fillna'].apply(make_printable)
                                                              .astype(int))
print (df)
   now_prices_after_fillna
0                     1450
1                     1500
```

Another idea if mixed numeric with strings values add `try` with except statement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'now_prices_after_fillna':['1450', u'\u200d1500', 1000]})
    
print (df)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451873/2901002
import sys

# build a table mapping all non-printable characters to None
NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE = {
    i: None for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode + 1) if not chr(i).isprintable()
}

def make_printable(s):
    """Replace non-printable characters in a string."""

    # the translate method on str removes characters
    # that map to None from the string
    try:
        return s.translate(NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE)
    except AttributeError:
        return s


df['now_prices_after_fillna'] = (df['now_prices_after_fillna'].apply(make_printable)
                                                              .astype(int))
print (df)
   now_prices_after_fillna
0                     1450
1                     1500
2                     1000
```

Test your real data:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_updated_file2222.xlsx')

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451873/2901002
import sys

# build a table mapping all non-printable characters to None
NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE = {
    i: None for i in range(0, sys.maxunicode + 1) if not chr(i).isprintable()
}

def make_printable(s):
    """Replace non-printable characters in a string."""

    # the translate method on str removes characters
    # that map to None from the string
    try:
        return s.translate(NOPRINT_TRANS_TABLE)
    except AttributeError:
        return s
```

---

```
df['price'] = df['price'].apply(make_printable).astype(int)

print (df)
     price
0     1450
1     1500
2      700
3     1700
4     2090
..     ...
206   1500
207   1290
208   1500
209   1560
210   1800

[211 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'translate'

Comment: @Elkhan - then use `df['now_prices_after_fillna'].astype(str).apply(make_printable).astype(int)`

Comment: error gone but problem is same it prints out like as in image I shared.

Comment: what type of solution?

Comment: Actually I work for two days on this problem.

Comment: @Elkhan - second paragraph solution

Comment: When I replace \u200d1500 with none all rows gone. I can not find any solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not understand what you mean by second paragraph solution @jezrael

Comment: @Elkhan - Is possible convert this problematic column to pickle and post by gdocs, dropbox, ... ?

Comment: @Elkhan - Solution bellow `Another idea if mixed numeric with strings values:` in my answer.

Comment: I'll post respected column .

Comment: @Elkhan - For pickle use `df[['now_prices_after_fillna']].to_pickle('u200.pkl')`

Comment: @Elkhan - Because I need test real data in this column, if post like text seems different (e.g. because non printable character)

Comment: yeah I understand you're definitely right.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/oly96d1n61i7fr3mhf0l8/your_updated_file2222.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=0rugo354eakvdbwvq7shvh1ax   @jezrael

Comment: Second paragraph worked. So thanks Jezrael.